# How to create several custom User models and be able to customize their admin forms?

Tags: django

**EDIT** I reformulated the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13837799/326849)

I want to create several custom user models extending `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, with the following features:

- some specific fields
- a nice admin, i.e., for each model, an admin form that I can customize easily (eg. show/hide some fields, both from the parent `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and the child model).

I almost managed to do it with the code below, but I still have an issue: the password is cleared every time I want to modify an instance of MyUser1 or MyUser2 from the admin.

Is it the best way to do it? If so, how can I fix this cleared password issue?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser1(User):
    #add more fields specific to MyUser1

class MyUser2(User):
    #add more fields specific to MyUser2
```

**admin.py**

```
    class MyUser1AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = MyUser1

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyUser1AdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(MyUser1AdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user


    class MyUser1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        form = MyUser1AdminForm


    admin.site.register(MyUser1, MyUser1Admin)

# same for MyUser2
```

Comment: I think you need to use ReadOnlyPasswordHashWidget as in UserChangeForm in admin for User model, because password is encrypted. Look at django/contrib/auth/forms.py and django/contrib/auth/admin.py.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: No, I'm using 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

if you whant for user to enter pass - add new field for pass and check it before commit

```
class MyUser1AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    check_pass = forms.CharField(label="Password",widget = forms.PasswordInput(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser1
        exclude = ('password',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyUser1AdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit and user.check_password(self.cleaned_data["check_pass"]):
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: I want the password to be required.

Comment: The `check_pass` field is not visible in the admin.

Comment: This cannot work: the password is never set to the parent model. Moreover, the `check_pass` field is still cleared when going to the change page.

Comment: For what purpose you want to ask pass on edit page? 1) For security reason 2) For ability to change pass.  If 1) - i think it's correct to  have empty field.

Comment: I want my custom users to have `add` and `change` forms similar to the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` forms. Moreover in your code, the password is not set.

Comment: you can't change password on default user form, django has specific form for password change. You can see examples in django/contrib/auth/admin.py

Comment: On default user add form, the steps are: fill username and password, save, fill remaining fields, save. And in the change form you cannot directly modify the password, but there is a link to the change password form. I want exactly that, with my additional fields.