# How to add fields in extended UserAdmin

Tags: django

I'm trying to create custom user models with their own admins (`add` and `change` forms). I'd like to have exactly the same as the original User admin with just the additional fields in the `add` and `change` forms.

Anybody could help?

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser1(User):
    #add more fields specific to MyUser1

class MyUser2(User):
    #add more fields specific to MyUser2
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class MyUser1Admin(UserAdmin):
    # how can I add the "fields specific to MyUser1" both in the add
    # and the change forms?

admin.site.register(MyUser1, MyUser1Admin)


# same for MyUser2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to extend the UserCreationForm and UserChangeForm:

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class MyUser1CreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    myuser1_field = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "myuser1_field", "password1", "password2")

class MyUser1ChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    myuser1_field = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

class MyUser1Admin(UserAdmin):

    form = MyUser1ChangeForm
    add_form = MyUser1CreationForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('myuser1_field', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )


    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'myuser1_field', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )


admin.site.register(MyUser1, MyUser1Admin)
```

Comment: Say `myuser1_field` is a field in the custom user model. Is there a way to create the field using the definition in models

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class MyUser1AdminForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser1
```

Comment: I also need to override the add form: some of the extra fields are required, and they are not in the original user add form, so I get an IntegrityError when saving. The extra fields are not in the change form.